# Is there a way that we can trigger a shell script from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I trigger a shell script which is available in local folder in linux to run through an API which is containerized .

Through docker container I want to trigger the shell script which is available in local folder

```
services:

  webui:
    image: sample/webui
    container_name: webui
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app:rw
    networks:
      - sampleApp

apis:
    image: sample/apis
    container_name: apis
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: apis/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8686:8686
    volumes:
      - ..:/data/sw_data:rw
    networks:
      - sampleApp


networks: {sampleApp: {}}

volumes:
  data:
```

Comment: A major design goal of Docker is that you can't.  Run the other task inside the container, or run your application without a container (the `volumes:` suggests you're trying to run host code and not an isolated application in any case).  You can, technically, sort of, with a lot of setup, and the linked question describes this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mount your script and then have to run it like below. Here I added two lines. One in volume and another is command. Volume will add script in docker and the command will run that script.

```
apis:
image: sample/apis
container_name: apis
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: apis/Dockerfile
ports:
  - 8686:8686
command: ["/data/scripts/run.sh"]
volumes:
  - ..:/data/sw_data:rw
  - <script-folder>:/data/scripts
networks:
  - sampleApp
```

Comment: then in api container I have to mention the script path to run it, whether I should provide the local path of script or container path

Comment: You need to pass container path `command: ["/data/scripts/run.sh"]` Here you can see that. I passed container path. It will run inside container.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to defeat original purpose of container: to isolate an app in the container from the rest of the system to protect the underlying host from any effect caused by the application in the container. You can do this though:

1. The container still have possibility to connect to port on the host. Listen on the host with simple server that would run the script.
2. If you are happy with just running the script that resides in the local folder, simply mount the folder to the container and run it from there.

Following example with show both of these methods.

Create these files `server.py` and `client.py`:

`server.py`:

```py
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = '172.17.0.1'  # docker host in virtual network
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1) # Enable the server to accept connections (max 1 client)
print(f"Listening for connections on port {port}...")

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print(f"Connection received from {addr}")
    os.system("echo Hi")  # Here will go yours script
    c.send(b'Hi, you are connected.\n')
    c.close()
```

`client.py`:

```py
import socket

HOST = '172.17.0.1'
PORT = 12345

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    data = s.recv(1024)

print(f'Received: {data.decode("utf-8")}')
```

Start the server on the host:

```
python server.py
```

Now we will mount the script client into the container and trigger the script (`echo Hi` in our case) on the host:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd)/client.py:/client.py python python /client.py
```

Comment: can you provide some sample as I am new to docker container

Comment: I have provided something for you.